# Objective-C: How to play a video from a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Bellow i have some code that should play a video once the user has selected the video he wants by name in a `uitableview`:

```
    NSLog(@"url %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

  NSString *currentFileName = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];
   NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

   //Play the movie now
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];
[[movieController view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];
[self.view addSubview: [movieController view]];
[movieController play];
```

The code should take `filePathsArray` which is just the name of the file in my documents directory and of corse i cannot use just a name of a file to play a video it must be a full path. For example i need to get the full path like in the simulator. "/Users/UserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications" instead i am getting just the name of the file for example "123.mp4".

The problem with the code is this line:`NSString *currentFileName = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];` an once again that is due to just receiving the file name. The problem causes the simulator to crash and i receive this:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xc08384e7)
```

Can anybody help?

Edit

I placed `NSLog(@"row %i - filePathsArray %@", indexPath.row, filePathsArray);`
 in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}` where my other codes are and i received once again the thread error but i then put the `NSLog(@"row %i - filePathsArray %@", indexPath.row, filePathsArray);` in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

and that displayed in the debugger output:

```
filePathsArray (
    "1372954494.023550.mp4",
    "1372954525.440379.mp4",
    "1372954698.070642.mp4",
    "1372954717.124080.mp4",
    "1372954881.568860.mp4",
    "1372954995.932892.mp4",
    "1372955079.400627.mp4",
    "1372955121.735828.mp4",
    "1372955151.191822.mp4",
    "1372955204.253028.mp4",
    "1372955317.622774.mp4",
    "1372955394.617367.mp4",
    "1372955455.130194.mp4",
    "1372955748.579562.mp4",
    "1372955801.431035.mp4",
    "1372955982.626679.mp4",
    "1372956220.934516.mp4",
    "1372956313.205083.mp4",
    "1372956396.179499.mp4",
    "1372956433.715887.mp4",
    "1372956521.383647.mp4",
    "1372956556.635456.mp4",
    "1372956865.871915.mp4",
    "1372957260.725387.mp4",
    "1372957729.062718.mp4",
    "1372957817.498707.mp4",
    "1372958542.838564.mp4",
    "1372958898.002360.mp4",
    "1372958944.864006.mp4",
    "1372958981.295354.mp4",
    "1372959288.333242.mp4",
    "1372959511.324370.mp4",
    "1372959557.161786.mp4",
    "1372959979.054552.mp4",
    "1372960381.754023.mp4",
    "1372960609.649583.mp4",
    "1372964668.874020.mp4",
    "1372964985.709783.mp4",
    "1372965088.565757.mp4",
    "1372965163.876937.mp4",
    "1372965296.464444.mp4",
    "1373027973.427050.mp4",
    "1373028300.018729.mp4",
    "1373028402.868729.mp4",
    "1373031752.143091.mp4"
)
```

which are all the correct names of my saved files.

**EDIT**

Here is my full code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(!filePathsArray)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ([filePathsArray count] > 0)
        return [filePathsArray count];
    else
        return 0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil]mutableCopy];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"row %i - filePathsArray %@", indexPath.row, filePathsArray);

    NSString *currentFileName = filePathsArray[indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"url %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

 //Play the movie now
   movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];
 [[movieController view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];
   [self.view addSubview: [movieController view]];
   [movieController play];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }



    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSLog(@"urlstring %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the output of the NSLog on your first line? Is there really a path or just the filename?
In case it's just the filename, you'd have to change the filepath to: NSString *currentFileName = filePathsArray[indexPath.row];

Comment: @Swissdude it's just a file name for the filePathArray

Comment: @Swissdude and your code is still causing the crash

Comment: Is your movie really in the documents folder of your app? What does an NSLog of fileURL say? Make sure the path is correct and the the movie's really at the expected location. Also, the simulator is case insensitive, while the actual device is case sensitive. So «Movie.mp4» would find «movie.mp4» on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: @Swissdude Yes the movie is really there! Tried on device and caused a crash and tried the `nslog` function on `fileURL` but it will not show because of crashing on this line: `NSString *currentFileName = filePathsArray[indexPath.row];`

Comment: then, there's something wrong with the array and the index. What's the output of NSLog(@"url %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); ? - Actually, it should crash there already... does the crash still produce an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: @Swissdude Yes it does produce EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Did you try using NSString *currentFilename = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ? If the the NSLog spits out the correct filename, using this should not crash your app anymore...

Comment: @Swissdude yes i did use `NSString *currentFilename = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: So just to make it clear for me: when you use NSLog(@"url %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); you get the correct filename, but it crashes on NSString *currentFilename = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ???

Comment: @Swissdude No this `NSLog(@"url %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);`
and this line `NSString *currentFilename = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` cause it to crash and display `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: ahhh - ok... :) do me a favor and post the output of the following: NSLog(@"row %i - filePathsArray %@", indexPath.row, filePathsArray); - Add it as an edit to your original question, please. You're most likely trying to access an index in your array that doesn't exist.

Comment: I can't really figure out what's wrong. When your app crashes in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, there might be something wrong with the table-delegate... Could you post the entire code into your edits? I'm pretty sure your bug is somewhere in the initial methods...
Did you set up the tableview.datasource and tableview.delegate correctly? It seems like the filePathsArray is lost or nil'd by the time you reach didSelectRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure that you're not correctly initializing your array. In your viewDidLoad-method try: filePathsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil]mutableCopy]]; - I take that you added a property in your .h-file that's called NSArray *filePathsArray ?

Comment: @Swissdude Thank you so much for your answer make a real answer with that code and i will tick it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By request, here's the solution:

In the viewDidLoad-method, you have to allocate the array:

```
filePathsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]mutableCopy]];
```